# Why does this show after running my C program?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

So, after running this code in Visual Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
     printf("Hello!");
     return 0;
}
```

I get this in my console:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84foo.png)
What's up with all that added text?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're running your program under Visual Studio Code's debugger, and for some reason it prints out a bit of job control trash on the console.

Maybe add a newline at the end of your print, to make your output clearer:

```
printf("Hello!\n");
```

Alternatively, don't run under the debugger (look for a "Run without debug" option).